# Using an inline svg as a pseudoelement with styled components returns an error

Tags: reactjs, svg

I have a NextJS app and using react-inline-svg.  This automatically turns an svg into a React component.  However, whenever I try to use this svg on a pseudo element I get the following error:

```
Module parse failed: Identifier 'React' has already been declared (2:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import React from "react";
> import React from "react";
| import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';
```

I'm not sure how to get around this issue.

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

import GreenArrow from '../../../static/images/greenarrow.svg';

h3::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(${GreenArrow});
    background-size: 8px 12px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
```